# An inequality with $a^3+b^3+c^3=a^4+b^4+c^4$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers and $a^3+b^3+c^3=a^4+b^4+c^4$. Prove that: $$\frac{a}{a^2+b^3+c^3}+\frac{b}{b^2+c^3+a^3}+\frac{c}{c^2+a^3+b^3}\ge1$$

**My solve:** So we have $$\frac{a^2}{a^3+ab^3+ac^3}+\frac{b^2}{b^3+bc^3+ba^3}+\frac{c^2}{c^3+ca^3+cb^3}\ge\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{a^3+b^3+c^3+ab^3+ac^3+bc^3+ba^3+ca^3+cb^3}$$
Now because $a^3+b^3+c^3=a^4+b^4+c^4$ so $$a^3+b^3+c^3+ab^3+ac^3+bc^3+ba^3+ca^3+cb^3$$$$=a^4+b^4+c^4+ab^3+ac^3+bc^3+ba^3+ca^3+cb^3$$$$=(a+b+c)(a^3+b^3+c^3)$$
But I can't prove $a+b+c=a^3+b^3+c^3$. If you have an idea, then please let me know,  thank you!

Comment: On AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1735896p11269538.

Comment: Hint:- $(a+b+c)^{3}=a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3}+3(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)\ge a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3}+3(a+b+c)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For positive $x$, $f(x)=(x-x^3)-2(x^3-x^4)=x(x-1)^2(2x+1)\geqslant 0$.  Hence $f(a)+f(b)+f(c) = (a+b+c)-(a^3+b^3+c^3) \geqslant 0$.

Comment: Thank you, I can do it now